# PhysicsBody larger than Texture it is assigned to (pictures)

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I have been having an issue with one of my sprites "`physicsBody`" property.

I have placed the `physicsBody` node "`barn`", directly on top of a `non-physicsBody` node "`mound`" without any issue. It looks fine on the simulator, but my node "`hero`" keeps bumping into an invisible barrier, that no longer poses a problem when I remove "`barn`" (so it must be an issue with the "`barn`"). The `physicsBody` element of `barn` seems to be extending down the `y` farther than the actual texture is. I.E. The `physicsBody` and the texture seem to be in two different places, despite the fact that the parameters of my `physicsBody` consist of the texture:

```
let barn = SKSpriteNode(texture: barn.texture, size: barn.size)
barn.physicsBody?.dynamic = false
barn.physicsBody?.pinned = true
barn.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false

barn.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), CGRectGetMinY + mound.size.height / 2)
```

As you can see in the following picture,  when I apply an impulse to the "`hero`" node (the black circle sitting on top of the tan bar on the bottom) it gets stopped by some kind of invisible node:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/vdq5p.png

If I continue to apply an impulse it goes up into the node, following the same kind of shape pattern, but as if it was just dropped maybe 50 pixels:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/DVUD1.png

If I add a 150 pixel space to the `y-value` like so:

```
barn.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), CGRectGetMinY(self.frame) + mound.size.height / 2 + 150)
```

Then the "`hero`" node can properly move as it should:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/0BtNe.jpg

So what we can deduce is essentially the `physicsbody` seems to be way down the `y-axis` despite the texture being properly placed on top of the mound. I am new to swift, can anyone make any sense of this? Thanks.

Comment: If you set `view.showsPhysics = true` in `didMoveToView`, an outline of the physics bodies will appear in your scene. I suspect you will see what's causing the issue.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else having an issue with this, I found the problem to be in my anchorPoint.

anchorPoint only works for the node itself and not the " physicsBody ".